# Revit API : Access components in particular floor using Autodesk.Revit.DB

Tags: autodesk, revit-api

I am working on a pluggin for revit 2019: trying to obtain list of rooms and tags segregated seperately for each floor in a revit model using c#, I have been able to obtain all the rooms data in the entire model but unable to segregate based on particular floors.

I am also unable to find how to obtain floors object list from data tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup)?

It is an interactive Revit BIM database exploration tool to view and navigate element properties and relationships.

Using that, you can see what properties the room elements have and use those to classify them as required.

A well-built BIM would probably normally define a separate level for each floor and place each room element on the corresponding level, making it easy to achieve what you need using a suitable [filtered element collector](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.9).